# Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException' was thrown

Tags: azure, storage

Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException' was thrown.

Sometimes even if we have the fabric running and the role manager is up, we get an exception of this sort.

The code breaks at the line:

```
 emailAddressClient.CreateTableIfNotExist("EmailAddress");
```

---

```
public EmailAddressDataContext(CloudStorageAccount account) :
            base(account.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, account.Credentials)
{
   this.storageAccount = account;

   CloudTableClient emailAddressClient =
                new CloudTableClient(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, 
                                     storageAccount.Credentials);
   emailAddressClient.CreateTableIfNotExist("EmailAddress");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I give Windows Azure tables camel-cased names all the time without issues.

I wonder if by chance you already used this table name and recently deleted it?  For a time after deletion (when the table is still being deleted asynchronously), you won't be able to recreate it.  I believe 409 Conflict is the error code to expect in that case.

Comment: Nopes. I recreated the issue after deleting the table name using Storage explorer. Same issue and same answer. What version of SDK are you using? Anyways, this worked for me and i blogged it as the exception is misleading. i would mark it resolved.

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether or not the delete actually finished in time.  If you look at the detail of the exception (easiest to do by just running Fiddler), my guess is you'll see what the real error is.

Comment: It is part of my blog post where the first exception happens, which when fixed leads to another exception. Delete actually finished as i said i used the storage explorer so how could it not return the table if it was not deleted. it shows it as deleted. however, i understand what the problem is - i forgot to put the link to the blogs where this problem came in as a succession to the other problem. Read this http://weblogs.asp.net/chanderdhall

Comment: The blog post claims camel casing is the issue.  I keep pushing back because I don't want future readers of this question to be misled.

Table deletion is asynchronous... it will show as deleted right away, but if you try to recreate it before the deletion is complete, you'll get a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Steve Marx, casing does not seem to affect this issue.  In fact Microsoft's Azure diagnostics tables are created with unusual casing eg: WADPerformanceCounters.  I get the problem even in the dev environment.  So it is something else entirely - my opinion.

Error fixed in my case: The problem was an error with the connection string as defined in (or lack thereof) in the webrole or workerrole project properties.
Fix:
Right-click on the webrole under "Roles" folder in your cloud application. Select "Properties" from the context menu.
Select the "Settings" tab.
Verify or Add a setting for you connection string that you will use to initialize table storage.

Mine was a simple error - no setting for my connection string.

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix is to change "EmailAddress" to "Emailaddress". For some reasons it would not allow CamelCasing. So please make sure, you just have one capital letter in the name of the table that too at the beginning. Since the table names are case insensitive, you can also name it as 'emailaddress'

Comment: Camel casing is not the issue. You have come to a wrong conclusion in your haste. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx