# A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to use a queue and here is the exception i am getting:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

I also checked this question but couldnt find my answer: 
[Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException' was thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221090/exception-of-type-microsoft-windowsazure-storageclient-storageclientexception)

this is the code:

```
    storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    rawMessageQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("rawMessageQueue");

    private CloudQueue rawMessageQueue;
    var QueueExists = rawMessageQueue.Exists();
```

Comment: what is the call stack of the exception?

Comment: Your queue name is invalid. It should be all lowercase. Please see this link for queue naming rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179349.aspx.

Comment: You could have identify the root cause by looking into e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage

Answer (score 1):

Just update the following dlls:

1. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
2. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll

[image]

Then rebuild .